# Creating a login/register form

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a vb form, which allows a person to create an "account". I store the usernames and passwords in two arrays, and extract the information from them. But when I run the program, it comes up with a problem:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, Additional information: Value
>   cannot be null."

where the code for the Button2/Register Button is (To be exact:

```
 For i = 0 To (UBound(Usernames))
```

Could you help me out and tell me what to do differently/how to approach this situation? Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1

        Dim Usernames() As String
        Dim Passwords() As String
        Dim CurrName As String
        Dim i As Integer
        'Login button is pressed
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim Index As Integer
            CurrName = TextBox1.Text
            For i = 0 To (UBound(Usernames))
                If IfRepetition(Usernames, CurrName, i) = True Then
                    Index = Array.IndexOf(Usernames, TextBox1.Text)
                    If TextBox2.Text = Passwords(Index) Then
                        Form3.Show()
                        Me.Hide()
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox("The username or password is incorrect", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                End If
            Next
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            CurrName = TextBox1.Text

            ' *** Error (apparently) happens here ***
            For i = 0 To (UBound(Usernames))
                If IfRepetition(Usernames, CurrName, i) = True Then
                    MsgBox("This username already exists!")
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve Usernames(UBound(Usernames) + 1)
                    Usernames(UBound(Usernames)) = TextBox1.Text

                    ReDim Preserve Passwords(UBound(Passwords) + 1)
                    Passwords(UBound(Passwords)) = TextBox2.Text
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
        Private Function IfRepetition(ByRef Usernames() As String, CurrName As String, i As Integer) As Boolean
            Dim j As Integer
            'Checks for repetition of a username in the usernames array
            IfRepetition = False

            For j = 0 To (UBound(Usernames))
                If Usernames(j) = CurrName Then
                    IfRepetition = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next

        End Function
End Class
```

Comment: "_all sorts of different problems_" You will need to be more specific than that

Comment: instead of copy pasting what you find on internet try understanding. You say many problems but cant explain them?

Comment: "all sorts of different problems" doesn't really tell us anything about the problem.  Perhaps you can be a *little* more specific?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site and `all sorts of different problems` means you want us to debug your app for you (and makes this post too broad for SO).  No one can fix `all sorts of different problems` *en masse*, so fix them one at a time.  When you get stuck post a specific problem and your efforts.  Please study [ask] and take the [tour] before posting again

Comment: Sorry, Mederic, for that formulation, but I don't just copy and paste off the Internet, that's why I asked the question - to understand.

Comment: Tip: Research each error one at a time: what does it mean?  What does MSDN say about it?  What does the code look like in SO posts related to the error.  If you are aBegginer, the point is to learn stuff, not weirdos on the intenet feeding you code that you may not understand. [Two things you want to avoid](http://i.imgur.com/CHJrDi6.jpg)

Comment: Tip #2 re Edit: `where the code for the Button2/Register Button is` is still imprecise - that is a block of 15 or so lines of code.  The exception happens on a *specific line*.  Help us help you.  Some here may be 'stealing' time from work to help you.  Dont make it difficult to help you by making us guess where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is because UBound throws exception if the array is null.
Also using arrays for that isn't a good way, I recommend you use Dictionary for easier, shorter code.

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'A new dictionary which handles usernames & passwords

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Login button
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then 'Check the entered username, if it's empty show error message and return ( don't continue )
        MessageBox.Show("Enter the username")
        Return
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then 'Check the entered password, if it's empty show error message and return ( don't continue )
        MessageBox.Show("Enter the password")
        Return
    End If

    If Not dic.ContainsKey(TextBox1.Text) Then 'Check the entered username, if it doesn't exist show error message and return ( don't continue )
        MessageBox.Show("The username is incorrect")
        Return
    End If
    If dic(TextBox1.Text) <> TextBox2.Text Then 'Validate entered username and password, if it's wrong show error message and return ( don't continue )
        MessageBox.Show("The password is incorrect")
        Return
    End If
    Form3.Show() 'If none of above error messages appear which means the entered username and password are correct, show Form3 and hide this form
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'create account button
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then 'Check the entered username, if it's empty show error message and return ( don't continue )
        MessageBox.Show("Enter the username")
        Return
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then 'Check the entered password, if it's empty show error message and return ( don't continue )
        MessageBox.Show("Enter the password")
        Return
    End If

    If dic.ContainsKey(TextBox1.Text) Then 'Check the entered username, if it exists show error message and return ( don't continue )
        MessageBox.Show("This username already exists")
        Return
    End If

    dic.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) 'If none of above error messages which means it's okay to create this account, Add the username & password to the dictionary
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly. Appreciate your help!